# XML to JSON merges tags

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am working on a small project and I have encountered an issue for which I cannot find a solution myself or locate something similar on internet. So, I am retrieving information from API in XML format, when I call my own API through JavaScript to retrieve this XML document the data gets converted into JSON format, but the repeating tags get merged into single property. Anyone know how I can stop it ?

Here is some Sample data:

```
<then>
            <test operator="test">
                <one>
                        <byte>1</byte>
                </one>
                <two>
                        <byte>1</byte>
                </two>
            </test>
            <insert>
                <object>
                        <string>1</string>
                </object>
            </insert>
            <remove>
               <object>url</object>
            </remove>
            <test operator="test">
                <one>
                        <byte>3</byte>
                </one>
                <two>
                        <byte>3</byte>
                </two>
            </test>
</then>
```

After serialization the output would look like this:

```
{
    "then": {
        "test": [
            {
                "one": {
                    "byte": "1"
                },
                "two": {
                    "byte": "1"
                },
                "_operator": "test"
            },
            {
                "one": {
                    "byte": "3"
                },
                "two": {
                    "byte": "3"
                },
                "_operator": "test"
            }
        ],
        "insert": {
            "object": {
                "string": "1"
            }
        },
        "remove": {
            "object": "url"
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that all test have been merged into 1 property. Is there any way to stop this ?

Comment: This is an implicit consequence of the conversion as JSON requires unique keys. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Yes you are right I completely forgot about this. Well at the end of the day it would still be useful to separate them and change their keys by adding a number meaby. It is important for me to keep the order of the data.

Comment: Well if you need custom conversions write a custom converter   :)

Comment: Well I guess this is my only option or changing the entire code to read XML instead of JSON. Either way thanks for clarification :)